# Why javax.mail port changed from 2525 to 25

Tags: java, smtp, port, mandrill, jakarta-mail

I use mandrill to send mails. Port is set to 2525

```
props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
//props.put("mail.smtp.**ssl.enable", "true");
//props.put("mail.smtp.**ssl.required", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", settings.host);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", settings.port);
```

And I am sure that all setting are valid.

Then I set authenticator

```
authenticator = new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(settings.username, settings.password);
    }
};
```

And sfter that send mail

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
session.setDebug(true);
try {
    Message message = mail.getMessage(session); 
    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Done");
    return true;
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    return false;
}
```

Debug says that I send mail on 25th port

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.s
mtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mandrillapp.com", port 25, isSSL fal
se
220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.mandrillapp.com", port: 25
```

I tried to create "smtps" transport, but that didn't help. Mandrill says that I can use port 2525 (or 587, and other). I also send on port 2525 using postfix from linux server with same credentials.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but port 25 is the "default" for mail stuff ( http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/portnumbers.asp for example)

Comment: Are you sure that "settings.port" is 2525?

Comment: @YoriKusanagi Yes, I checked that many times and just hardcoded that value

Comment: @Jägermeister I found this error when moved code to google VM Instance. Maybe this bug is old, I had opened 25th port on old server, and didn't think that mails were sent through it. But on new server 25th port is closed by default, so I caught an error. And during debug I realized that mails are sent on 25 port.

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite stupid)

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", settings.port);
```

in this line port is an `int` value, when I changed `port` field to `String` it started working.